# How To get Specific dates and Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, date, datetime

my variables = ORDate , quantity, purchaseOrderDate, purchaseOrderTime

business day include (monday to friday)

```
Example Purchase Order Time = 20211015 (yyyyMMdd) (2021-10-15)
Example: Purchase Order Time = 093310 (hhmmss)   (09:33:10)
```

**If the order is Blank and is received before 2pm EST between M-F excluding US Holidays**

```
ORDate = Purchase Order Date
```

**If the order is Blank and is received after 2pm EST between M-F excluding US Holidays**

```
ORDate = Purchase Order Date + 1 day (between Monday-Friday excluding US Holidays)
```

**If the order is Blank with Finishing orders and is received before 2pm EST for orders less than 500 quantity between M-F excluding US Holidays**

```
ORDate =  Purchase Order Date + 1 day (between Monday-Friday excluding US Holidays)
```

**If the order is Blank with Finishing orders and is received after 2pm EST for orders less than 500 quantity between M-F excluding US Holidays**

```
ORDate = Purchase Order Date + 1 day + 1 additional business day.
```

**If the order is Blank with Finishing orders with more than 500 quantity between M-F excluding US Holidays**

Initial 500 quantiy ORDate = Next business day + 1 additional business day.

```
Each Additional 500 quantity ORDate = Purchase Order Date + 1 day + 1 extra additional business day for each 500 quantity .

if(purchaseOrderTime<2pm){
 purchaseOrderDate = BusinessDay
}
if(purchaseOrderTime>2pm){
 purchaseOrderDate = BusinessDay +1
}
```

Comment: Unclear how this is a C# question. Can you please show your code as a [mcve]?

Comment: What is your question?